# PHP Base class unable to find interfaces

Tags: php, pdo

I'm using Slim and bshaffer's OAuth2.0 library to build out an API. Currently I'm trying to extend the Pdo.php class included with the OAuth library to override a few functions. However, when I try to run my code, I'm getting an error saying:

> PHP Fatal error:  Interface
>   'OAuth2\Storage\AuthorizationCodeInterface' not found
>   /vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Storage/Pdo.php on line
>   21

Since that is the base class, and I don't want to modify it, I'm not sure how to address this issue.

Also, using the base Pdo class like so works fine, it's able to find the interfaces

```
$storage = new OAuth2\Storage\Pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $user, 'password' => $pw));
```

Here is my index.php file

```
<?php
use League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\SessionInterface;

require '/***/root/vendor/Slim/Slim.php';
require_once('/***/root/vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
require_once('/***/root/vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Storage/Pdo.php');
require_once('/***/root/custom_pdo.php');
OAuth2\Autoloader::register();

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post(
    '/token',
    function () {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname=DB';
        $user = MYSQL_USER;
        $pw = MYSQL_PASS;

        $storage = new custom_pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $user, 'password' => $pw));
        $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
        $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
        $response = $server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
        print_r($response);
    }
);

$app->run();
```

And here is my custom_pdo.php class

```
<?php

namespace OAuth2\Storage;

use OAuth2\OpenID\Storage\UserClaimsInterface;
use OAuth2\OpenID\Storage\AuthorizationCodeInterface as OpenIDAuthorizationCodeInterface;

require_once('/***/root/vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Autoloader.php');
require_once('/***/root/vendor/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/src/OAuth2/Storage/AuthorizationCodeInterface.php');


class custom_pdo extends Pdo {

}
```

Bshaffer Pdo class: https://github.com/bshaffer/oauth2-server-php/blob/develop/src/OAuth2/Storage/Pdo.php

Comment: Why you don't use composer?

You can install that component through composer (http://bshaffer.github.io/oauth2-server-php-docs/). Then in your bootstrap file load the vendor/autoload.php and you have everything already loaded and you don't have to deal with those requires.

Comment: @ssola Using Composer, I'm still in the same boat. I get one of two errors: either I get an error saying the class needs to implement a storage method (which extending Pdo class should do that), or that the class cannot find the interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it was a namespace issue. I wasn't calling my create object statement with the namespace, and that was causing the various issues I was running into. Here is the final code:

index.php

```
<?php
use League\OAuth2\Server\Storage\SessionInterface;

require '/***/root/vendor/autoload.php';
require "/***/root/custom_pdo.php";

$app = new \Slim\Slim();

$app->post(
    '/token',
    function () {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.MYSQL_HOST.';dbname=DB';
        $user = MYSQL_USER;
        $pw = MYSQL_PASS;

        $storage = new OAuth2\Storage\custom_pdo(array('dsn' => $dsn, 'username' => $user, 'password' => $pw));
        $server = new OAuth2\Server($storage);
        $server->addGrantType(new OAuth2\GrantType\ClientCredentials($storage));
        $response = $server->handleTokenRequest(OAuth2\Request::createFromGlobals())->send();
        print_r($response);
    }
);

$app->run();
```

custom.php

```
<?php

namespace OAuth2\Storage;

use OAuth2\OpenID\Storage\UserClaimsInterface;
use OAuth2\OpenID\Storage\AuthorizationCodeInterface as OpenIDAuthorizationCodeInterface;

class custom_pdo extends Pdo {

}
```